# blank desktop background

Tags: windows-7, windows

i have a problem with my desktop background.it is blank and any setting do not solve the problem.

Comment: do you mean the wallpaper ?

Comment: Is it simply that no images set as the desktop background will display, or is it that there is no start menu, task bar, or any other elements of the Windows user interface?

Comment: are you running a pirated version of Windows or Windows Starter?

Answer (score 3):

Any chance you see a tagline in the bottom right corner of your screen that says “This copy of Windows is not genuine.”?  If so it's, time to [activate Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/activate-windows-7-on-this-computer).

> **To activate by using a direct connection**
>
> Open Windows Activation by clicking the Start button , right-clicking Computer, clicking Properties, and then clicking Activate Windows now.
>
> If Windows detects an Internet connection, click Activate Windows online now.   If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Type your Windows 7 product key when prompted, click Next, and then follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It is genuine effect after disabling activation. You can purchase full version or you have to re-format entire windows. It happens again after expiration period finishes. So I suggest you buy license.